# How to watch all FormControls ValueChanges except specific control?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form that do a computation whenever a control input value changes.

Here is my `form_group` looks like:

```
form_group = this.fb.group({
    control1: [],
    control2: [],
    control3: [],
    ...
    control10: [],
});
```

I can detect all controls value changes via `form_group.valueChanges` observable, and do a computation. However i want to exclude some of the control that doesn't need to do such an action.

**But there is anyway how to not detect the changes on a particular control?**

It is very burdensome to write a `form_group.get('controlN').valueChanges` and do a computation there. I have 5 or more controls in my form.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can merge individual valueChanges Observables into one like so :

```
Observable.merge(
    [ control1.valueChanges,
      control2.valueChanges ]
  ).subscribe(() => {
    // do your computation
  });
```

Comment: It 's the same just think about it how do get control1 or another control refrence , and merage is the same like all the observable have one observer ,I think the problem not fixed yet ,I will be habe if I got from valueChange like this control has new value imagin like I have 50 item of formArray, good luck

Comment: now if you want to watch 9 of your controls you need 9 refrence so I still hope if there is a better way

Comment: @MuhammadAlbarmawi It works efficiently and with less code, rather than declaring subscription per control. And Yes of course it is the same with your suggestion the difference is simplicity.

Comment: Maybe you could put all the form controls you want to watch into a new group or FormArray so you can more easily manage them?

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why you couldn’t create a FormArray instead of multiple form controls? For example

```
form_group = this.fb.group({
    'controls': this.fb.array([...])
});
```

Then you can define a property in your component

```
get controls(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.form_group.get('control');
}
```

And then from this you can iterate the form array and subscribe to `valueChanges`

```
this.controls.controls.forEach(control => {
    control.valueChanges.subscribe(...)
});
```

You can then apply some logic in the for each to exclude the controls you do not want to subscribe to

Answer (score 3):

You can do it following way :

```
combineLatest(this.getControlsForWatch()).subscribe(() => applyFilter());

getControlsForWatch(): Array<Observable<any>> {
        return (
            Object.entries(this.from.controls)
                .filter(([key]) => key !== 'exceptedControl')
                .map(([key]) => this.from.controls[key].valueChanges)
        );
    }
```

also you can adjust filter for your current task

Answer (score 1):

Like so, I wanted to observe changes from multiple controls, I was able to do this like this.

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';
...
const merged = merge(this.control1.valueChanges,this.control2.valueChanges, this.control3.valueChanges, this.control4.valueChanges);

merged.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Reference:- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access to the control and subscribe to value changes property like this

```
    this.form_group.get('control1').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value)
    })
```

Comment: That is bad though, i want to avoid that since i have a lot of form control in my form and im seeking a much simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  control1: [''],
  control2: [''],
  excludedControl: [''], // The control you want to exclude
});

// Subscribe to value changes for all FormControls except excludedControl
Object.keys(this.myForm.controls)
  .filter(key => key !== 'excludedControl') // Exclude the specific control
  .forEach(controlName => {
    this.myForm.get(controlName).valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300), // Add any debounce time if needed
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(newValue => {
        // Handle the value change here
        console.log(`Value changed for ${controlName}: ${newValue}`);
      });
  });
```

}
}